# In javascript, 5 || 0 and 0 || 5 returns 5

Tags: javascript

As the title says everything. `5 || 0` and `0 || 5` returns `5` in JavaScript. Why does this happen and what does two `||` means in javascript?

Comment: || is Boolean logic 'OR'.

Comment: Short-circuit Evaluation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: Why does everyone seem to be discovering how Javascript's logical operators work this week? Seen this question a few times recently.

Comment: @deceze Comes up multiple times daily. :)

Comment: Get a good reference and look things up. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a `boolean or`, and 5 evaluates to [truthy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/). If you want to force your types to boolean you should use the `!!` (double negation) like so,

```
!!(5 || 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

`||` is a boolean or.

```
5 == true
0 == false
```

So, `5 || 0 = 5`

Answer (score 0):

The `||` is a synonym for the `logical OR`

So the statement `ANY_VALUE || ANY_OTHER_VALUE` means that if the first value is `truthy` then return that else return the second value